# opencv Mat initialization with zero runtime error

Tags: c++, opencv

When I try to initialize a `cv::Mat` with

```
mask = cv::Mat::zeros(20, 1, CV_8U);
```

or

```
mask = cv::Mat(20, 1, CV_8U, 1);
```

I seem to get a correctly initialized Mat. **But**

```
mask = cv::Mat(20, 1, CV_8U, 0);
```

throws this runtime error when I simply use `std::cout << mask.size() << std::endl;` or `std::cout << mask << std::endl;`

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total() == 0 || data != NULL) in Mat, file /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 579
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:579: error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != NULL in function Mat

which is strange... Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has following two constructors for Mat among many others:

```
Mat (int ndims, const int *sizes, int type, const Scalar &s);
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);
```

When you construct the Mat as in

```
mask = cv::Mat(20, 1, CV_8U, 0);
```

it uses the second constructor.

If you want to invoke the first constructor, you should do something like

```
mask = cv::Mat(20, 1, CV_8U, Scalar(0));
```

Comment: I think it's worthwhile to mention that this is NOT the assumption when compiling with Visual Studio 2020. I had perfectly functional code running on Windows that does not compile with g++ precisely due to this.